# How to apply a different dense layer to each row of a matrix in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

The output of my previous layer has the shape (None, 30, 600). I want to multiply each row of this matrix by a ***different*** (600, 600) matrix or equivalently multiply this matrix by a 3D weight matrix. This can be achieved by applying a different dense layer to each row. I tried using a TimeDistributed Wrapper but that applies the ***same*** dense layer to each row. I have also tried using a lambda layer like so:

```
Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack(x, axis=1))(
    Lambda(lambda x: [Dense(600)(each) for each in tf.unstack(x, axis=1)])(prev_layer_output)
)
```

This seemed to solve the problem and I was able to train the model correctly. But I noticed that model.summary() doesn't recognize these dense layers and neither are they reflected in the count of total Trainable params. Also, I am unable to restore their weights when I load the model and hence the whole training is wasted. How do I fix this problem? How do I apply a different dense layer to each row of a matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use several layers instead of wrapping everything into a single `Lambda` layer.

```py
x = Input((30, 600))
unstacked = Lambda(lambda x: K.tf.unstack(x, axis=1))(x)
dense_outputs = [Dense(600)(x) for x in unstacked]
merged = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack(x, axis=1))(dense_outputs)
model = Model(x, merged)
```

Now you can see 30 `Dense(600)` layers in `model.summary()`.

```py
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 30, 600)      0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               [(None, 600), (None, 0           input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][1]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][2]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][3]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][4]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][5]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][6]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][7]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)                 (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][8]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][9]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][10]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][11]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][12]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][13]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][14]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][15]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][16]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][17]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][18]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][19]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][20]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][21]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][22]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][23]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][24]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][25]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_27 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][26]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_28 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][27]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_29 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][28]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)                (None, 600)          360600      lambda_1[0][29]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               (None, 30, 600)      0           dense_1[0][0]
                                                                 dense_2[0][0]
                                                                 dense_3[0][0]
                                                                 dense_4[0][0]
                                                                 dense_5[0][0]
                                                                 dense_6[0][0]
                                                                 dense_7[0][0]
                                                                 dense_8[0][0]
                                                                 dense_9[0][0]
                                                                 dense_10[0][0]
                                                                 dense_11[0][0]
                                                                 dense_12[0][0]
                                                                 dense_13[0][0]
                                                                 dense_14[0][0]
                                                                 dense_15[0][0]
                                                                 dense_16[0][0]
                                                                 dense_17[0][0]
                                                                 dense_18[0][0]
                                                                 dense_19[0][0]
                                                                 dense_20[0][0]
                                                                 dense_21[0][0]
                                                                 dense_22[0][0]
                                                                 dense_23[0][0]
                                                                 dense_24[0][0]
                                                                 dense_25[0][0]
                                                                 dense_26[0][0]
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]
                                                                 dense_28[0][0]
                                                                 dense_29[0][0]
                                                                 dense_30[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 10,818,000
Trainable params: 10,818,000
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

---

**EDIT:** To verify that this model is learning:

```py
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
w0 = model.get_weights()
model.fit(np.random.rand(100,30,600), np.random.rand(100,30,600), epochs=10)
```

You should be able to see that the loss is decreasing:

```py
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 1s 15ms/step - loss: 0.4725
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2211
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2405
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2013
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1771
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1676
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1568
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1473
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1400
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1343
```

Also, you can verify that the weights indeed get updated by comparing the values before and after model fitting:

```py
w0 = model.get_weights()
model.fit(np.random.rand(100,30,600), np.random.rand(100,30,600), epochs=10)

w1 = model.get_weights()
print(not any(np.allclose(x0, x1) for x0, x1 in zip(w0, w1)))
# => True
```

Comment: I tried doing this. It allows the model to compile but the weight updates for the dense layers (calculated during back-propagation) do not get applied. Therefore, the model is not learning.

Comment: @hal9000 Well I tried compiling and fitting this model with some random data. Since the loss is decreasing in each epoch, it seems that this model **is** learning. Could you elaborate more about what you've tried? Maybe there's some other problem in your code.

Comment: See my edit for verifying that the model is learning. Maybe you could also check if there's any difference.

Comment: Yes, you were correct, the weights do get updated. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

you could multiply elementwise the (30,600) matrix with a (600,30,600) so you will obtain a (600,30,600), if you then sum over the last dimension and you should get what you want transposed. I tested this in numpy not in tensorflow but it should be the same